# How do i query for direct, indirect, and nested nodes depending on a starting node and a specific relation?

Tags: neo4j, nested, cypher, relationship, usergroups

I need to query the nodes owned by a user. I have the follwing simplified Graph:
[image: Graph Structure]

**INPUT:**
(User) PG

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

**973732e...** ,
**f7f3693...** ,
**9c572ae...**
**(OWNER_OF -->Group)**

I'm completely new to neo4j and cypher so i dont really know where to start. 
Does anyone have some pointers or any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```
// get all the paths
MATCH p= (u:User {name:'PG'})-[:MEMBER_OF|OWNER_OF*]->(:Group)

// extract the nodes that have an incoming  `OWNER_OF` relationship
WITH [node IN nodes(p) WHERE EXISTS(()-[:OWNER_OF]->(node))] AS ownedGroups

// get the distinct nodes
UNWIND ownedGroups AS ownedGroup
RETURN DISTINCT ownedGroups
```